# Can't make out one word in BBC documentary Civilization

Tags: word-request

I don't know if this kind of question is allowed here, but I'm going to ask anyway. In episode two of the BBC's documentary Civilization: Is The West History?, Mr. Ferguson, the narrator and presenter, says at 04:35

> Bells rang out in Vienna and all across central Europe summoning the faithful to pray for divine mercy. You can get an idea of the desperate yet defiant mood in Vienna from the graffiti in the old bell tower of the [St. Stephen's] Cathedral. This says: "Muhammad, you dog, X, go home!"

X denotes the word I can't figure out. The word sounds like "do hoond".

Episode link on Youtube:
https://youtube.com/watch?v=XGV1jAQVnBU

Answer (score 4):

After *you dog* the presenter says *Du Hund* (German for *you dog*), which are the actual words in the graffiti he is quoting. The graffiti is actually written in German (not English)  in the cathedral in Vienna. But your ears are good, as *Du Hund* sounds like *do hoond*.

Note that the German word *hund* and the English word *hound* are related. They both mean *dog* (= *hound*).

And a link for Part 2 is

https://youtu.be/Yc1me9jOxgk

You've given the link for part 3.